# XML type configuration files are not be identified by Spring Boot extension in VScode

Tags: xml, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I configured VScode by the following documents.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

Project is running normally after import my Spring Boot project.

This project used XML type of files to inject the beans. But VScode cannot identify the spring-beans.xml.

So that I cannot jump in the bean files and intelligently enter the classpath property.
like:

```
<bean id="XXXService" class="com.***.service.impl.XXXServiceImpl"/>
```

What kind of plugins can give me convenience?

Spring Boot support in VScode

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution that works for me, using "Spring Boot Tools" vscode extension  v1.47.0.

1. Go to vscode settings (File/Preferences/Settings or using CTRL+,).
2. Under Extensions/Spring Boot Tools/Feature, locate the configuration "boot-java.support-spring-xml-config.on".
3. Enable the "Support for Spring XML Config files"

Hoping it will help you and others...

BR,
Adrien